# Given that the roots of the equation $x^3-9x^2+bx-216=0$ are consecutive terms in a geometric sequence, find the value of b.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, polynomials, complex-numbers, roots

Given that the roots of the equation $x^3-9x^2+bx-216=0$ are consecutive terms in a geometric sequence, find the value of b.

First of all I found that 6 is a root of the equation: $\frac{α}{r}+α+αr=α^3,   α^3=216$ (product of the roots)

Then I used the remainder theorem and I got $b=54$. The answer should be $b=18$, so instead I factorized the equation using standard division and still got the same result.

Any hints how to get the correct solution?

Comment: sorry ignore my comment

Comment: For $b=18$ I get $3$ solutions which are not in geometric progression. And for $b=54$ either. For $b=54$ solutions are:
$$x=6,\;x= \frac{3}{2} \left(1-i \sqrt{15}\right),\;x= \frac{3}{2} \left(1+i \sqrt{15}\right)$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ be our roots.

Thus, $$\beta^2=\alpha\gamma,$$
$$\alpha+\beta+\gamma=9$$ and $$\alpha\beta\gamma=216.$$
Thus, from the first and the third we obtain:
$$\beta^3=216$$ or
$$\beta=6.$$
Thus, $$a+\gamma=3$$ and
$$\alpha\gamma=36.$$
Id est,
$$b=\alpha\beta+\alpha\gamma+\beta\gamma=6(\alpha+\gamma)+\alpha\gamma=6\cdot3+36=54,$$
which says that you are right and your book is wrong.

It's interesting that for $b=54$ we have
$$(x-6)(x^2-3x+36)=0,$$
which has no three real roots, but these roots are  geometric sequence.

Thus, or in the given should be $b$ is a real number or we need to work also with other two cases:

$$\beta=6(\cos120^{\circ}+i\sin120^{\circ});$$
$$\beta=6(\cos240^{\circ}+i\sin240^{\circ}).$$

Answer (score 2):

If the roots are consecutive terms in a geometric sequence, we have

$\alpha_1 = a$, $\alpha_2 = ar$, $\alpha_3 = ar^2$,

giving $a^3r^3 = -216$

Inspection tells us that there are various possibilities for $a$ and $r$, involving permutations of $-2$ and $-3$ (given that $216 = 2^33^3$).

Expanding out should give the desired result.